# Meteor + Polymer Styling - Style tag empty

Tags: meteor, polymer

Im trying to style a polymer component.

I have a html page with the following style:

```
<head>
<style is="custom-style">
  paper-input {
    --paper-input-container-focus-color: red;
  }
</style>
</head>
```

More often than not once meteor has rendered the page the style tag is empty. I have seen it a few times where the input is styled as expected. Im using latest meteor with iron:router and Polymer 1.0.6. Any help appreciated or if there's another way to style the components..

Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'main'
});

***Router***

```
Router.route('/',function() {
    this.layout('unauthenticated')
    this.render('signin');  
});
```

***Layout***

```
<template name="unauthenticated">  
  <body class="verticle layout">
    <div class="page">
      {{> yield}}
    </div>
  </body> 
</template>
```

**Template**

```
<template name="signin">
  <hgroup>
    <h1>Sign In</h1>
    <h3>Sign in with your Account</h3>
  </hgroup>

  <paper-material elevation="1">
    <form>
      <paper-input type="email" label="Email"></paper-input>
      <paper-input  type="password" label="Password"></paper-input>
    </form>
  </paper-material>  
</template>
```

***Imports***

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"> 

  <script src="/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>

  <link rel="import" href="/components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="/components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import" href="/components/paper-material/paper-material.html">

  <link rel="import" href="/components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
</head>
```

Comment: Can you just put the style info in client/style.css?

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with it.  But typically I don't see body tags inside another template.    Using body tags is just another way of saying template name="body". So maybe u could try including the unauthenticated  template within the body tags, not vice versa as you have done.

Comment: Yeah thats a fair point. I've removed the body tag to no avail. Im wondering if blaze has something to do with it. Im sure there must be other meteor devs doing the same thing I am?